# Node.js : How to do something on all HTTP requests in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, http, request, node.js-connect

I would like to do something like:

```
app.On_All_Incoming_Request(function(req, res){
    console.log('request received from a client.');
});
```

The current `app.all()` requires a path, and if I give for example this `/` then it only works when I'm on the homepage, so it's not really all..

In plain node.js it is as simple as writing anything after we create the http server, and before we do the page routing.

So how do I do this with express, and what is the best way to do it?

Comment: here's a tutorial I wrote on [writing express middleware](https://mguida.com/blog/writing-express-middleware/) to achieve this

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Express is based on the [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) middleware.

The routing capabilities of Express are provided by the `router` of your app and you are free to add your own middlewares to your application.

```js
var app = express.createServer();

// Your own super cool function
var logger = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("GOT REQUEST !");
    next(); // Passing the request to the next handler in the stack.
}

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(logger); // Here you add your logger to the stack.
    app.use(app.router); // The Express routes handler.
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

It's that simple.

(PS : If you just want some logging you might consider using the [logger](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-logger.html) provided by Connect)

Comment: hey, that was very easy. I'm using express with node.js for a while, but I never thought about this :-) thanks bro!

Comment: but @Raynos doesn't that has to go trough the routing process, and regular expressions etc...?

Comment: @CIRK it adds middleware to `app.router` instead of the server. I doubt it's significantly less efficient

Comment: @Raynos I feel like you should add an answer with the `app.all("*", cb)` solution, including discussion of why/why not to use it (I assume mostly stylistic). It is relevant to know the options.

Comment: `(PS : If you just want some logging you might consider using the logger provided by Connect)`

`connect.logger` is now [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)
Use something like `app.use(require('morgan')('combined'));

Comment: `app.configure` is not a function?

Answer (score 12):

You should do this:

```js
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req); // do anything you want here
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it by introducing a middleware function.
`app.use(your_function)` can be of help. `app.use` with accept a function that will get executed on every request logged to your server.
Example:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("req received from client");
    next(); // this will invoke next middleware function
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Express supports [wildcards in route paths](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths). So `app.all('*', function(req, res) {})` is one way to go.

But that's just for route handlers. The difference is that an Express route handler is expected to send a response, and, if it doesn't, Express will never send a response. If you want to do something without explicitly sending a response, like check for a header, you should use [Express middleware](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/middleware). `app.use(function(req, res, next) { doStuff(); next(); }`