# Capture all http requests with node/express

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking to capture all of the data from any request (images, fonts, css, js, etc) on my website so that I can capture the file details, specifically the file name and file size. I have found almost an identical question/solution:

[Node.js : How to do something on all HTTP requests in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263626/node-js-how-to-do-something-on-all-http-requests-in-express)

But the solution appears to be deprecated with Express v4. Is there a simple solution to do this? As another approach I have tried the below solution with no luck:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    // I want to listen to all requests coming from index.html
    res.send("index.html");
});

app.all("*", function(){
    // can't get requests
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Also I am not looking to do this from Fiddler/Charles because I am looking to display this data on my site.

Comment: Is logging request path and `Content-Length` header enough?

Comment: Hey @robertklep, possibly, I am not well versed in this area so it it allows me to grab the file name and kweight I think that should suffice.

Comment: In that case, using [morgan's `tiny` logger](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#tiny) may be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Express routes are predicated on **order**. Notice the answer that you linked in your question has the middleware defined, and used *before* all other routes.

Secondly you're trying to implement something that requires middleware, not a wildcard route. The pattern in link you provided in your question is not deprecated according to their [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // do something with the request
  req.foo = 'testing'
  next(); // MUST call this or the routes will not be hit
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if (req.foo === 'testing') {
      console.log('works');
    }

    res.send("index.html");
});
```